# Isaiah 37 and 2 Kings 19 are identical

Tags: isaiah, prophecy, kings, bible, christianity

Why do Isaiah 37 and 2 Kings 19 contain the same verses? Of course, consulting or referring to an older and reliable source of eyewitness information is expected and acceptable, but what is strange is that the writer of 2 Kings 19 has copied Isaiah 37 letter by letter. So why did he/she do that? Isn't it considered plagiarism? And in a holy book?

Comment: Thanks for your question and welcome to BHSE. Have you taken the tour to see the particulars of this site? It would be helpful to us if you edited in the exact words you are comparing + which version so that we can see precisely what you are asking?

Comment: "Plagiarism" is an offence created by the modern competitive bookmarket. Nobody would see anything immoral in using the same words to describe an historical event.

Comment: It is possible that Isaiah was the author of this part of 2 kings.

Comment: This is a duplicate of a previous question. If factual information is in the public domain, and is quoted verbatim as evidence there is no 'plagiarism' and no copyright issue. They are commonly known facts.

Answer (score 1):

From the original post:

> Why do Isaiah 37 and 2 Kings 19 contain the same verses?

The short answer is that the books of Isaiah and 2 Kings tell stories from different perspectives. The passages in question are where the two stories overlap so many of the same words are used.

Isaiah tells the story of God's sovereign majesty and redemptive love for God's people who are destined for both judgement, because of unfaithfulness, and salvation as told to God's people through the prophet Isaiah.

1 and 2 Kings start with the reign of Solomon and tells the story the monarchy, it's division into two kingdoms, the decline of the monarchy and eventual removal of God's people from the land. 1 and 2 Kings was written to answer the question "In light of God's covenant with Abraham and David how did we end up in captivity?"

In 2 Kings 19 and Isaiah 37 the two stories overlap.
In Isaiah 36:1 the story of Judah under attack by the Assyrians begins. Isaiah plays a major role in that story.
In 2 Kings 18 the story of King Hezekiah's rule is told. Since the Assyrian attack and Isaiah's role in the story are a critical part of King Hezekiah's story we see the same story told - word for word.

The two books are written from different perspectives. In this case the stories overlap and the same words are used.

From the original post:

> Isn't it considered plagiarism? And in a holy book?

There was no concept of a copyright in ancient times.

> During the Roman Empire, a period of prosperous book trade, no
> copyright or similar regulations existed

The kings of Judah and Israel existed hundreds of years before Rome.

[Wikipedia - History of copyright](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_copyright)

> The world's first copyright law was the Statute of Anne, enacted in
> England in 1710. This Act introduced for the first time the concept of
> the author of a work being the owner of its copyright, and laid out
> fixed terms of protection. Following this Act, copyrighted works were
> required to be deposited at specific copyright libraries, and
> registered at Stationers' Hall. There was no automatic copyright
> protection for unpublished works.

[Intellectual Property Rights Office](https://iprightsoffice.org/copyright_history/#:%7E:text=The%20world%27s%20first%20copyright%20law%20was%20the%20Statute,copyright%2C%20and%20laid%20out%20fixed%20terms%20of%20protection.)

Since the Bible is inspired by God and written by people even if there were copyright laws who would be plagiarized?

Comment: If you *know* it's a duplicate question, then don't answer it, close it instead!

Answer (score 0):

Although minor differences have been observed, either Isaiah 37 or 2 Kings 19 appears to have been largely copied from one source to the other. Here are two possible explanations:

- Isaiah was an eyewitness - or at least was a counsellor to the King of Judah at the time - so his account must have been written first, while the Books of Kings were composed centuries after the event. In this scenario, the historian who wrong 2 Kings inserted the highly reliable earlier account of Isaiah.
- The Book of Isaiah is not the product of one author. The account from 2 Kings was inserted into Isaiah by a later editor. Supporting this view is the fact that the language of this part of the Book of Isaiah is uncharacteristic of prophetic writing, while it is generally consistent with the style of 2 Kings.

The OP asks if copying this way (either way) would be considered plagiarism. We might consider it so today, but both scenarios I have presented involve a process in which the original author could not have lost any monetary value, nor would they even have been alive at the time the copying was done. The editor in question would simply be inserting relevant material that he considered useful for his readers. He would not be claiming credit for it either, since in both cases we are dealing with an anonymous editor, not an author claiming the words to be his own.